# Python: Splitting parts of a URL for use in a function

Tags: python, curl

I understand there are many answers already on SO dealing with split python URL's. BUT, I want to split a URL and then use it in a function.

I'm using a curl request in python:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/twofishes?query=New%York')
r.json()
```

Which provides the following:

```
{'interpretations': [{'what': '',
  'where': 'new york',
  'feature': {'cc': 'US',
    'geometry': {'center': {'lat': 40.742185, 'lng': -73.992602},
     ......
     # (lots more, but not needed here)
```

I want to be able to call any city/location, and I want to separate out the `lat` and `lng`. For example, I want to call a function where I can input any city, and it responds with the latitude and longitude. Kind of like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489815/scraping-data-using-rvest-and-a-specific-error) (which uses R).

This is my attempt:

```
import requests

def lat_long(city):
    geocode_result = requests.get('http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/twofishes?query= "city"')
```

How do I parse it so I can just call the function with a city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your example, I'd suggest using regex and string interpolation.  This answer assumes the API returns data the same way every time.

```
import re, requests

def lat_long(city: str) -> tuple:
    # replace spaces with escapes
    city = re.sub('\s', '%20', city)
    res = requests.get(f'http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/twofishes?query={city}')

    data = res.json()
    geo = data['interpretations'][0]['feature']['geometry']['center']

    return (geo['lat'], geo['lng'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over this list 'interpretations' looking for the city name, and return the coordinates when you find the correct city.

```
def lat_long(city):
    geocode_result = requests.get('http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/twofishes?query= "city"')
    for interpretation in geocode_result["interpretations"]:
        if interpretation["where"] == city:
            return interpretation["feature"]["geometry"]["center"]
```